# click a data toggle button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, button, triggers, click, toggle

I have a form which has four data toggle tabs and a submit button at the 4th tab. So when I click the submit button, I am showing a popup alert on which filed is not correct. But it should navigate to my 1st tab.
So how can I click a data toggle button using jquery ? 
I tried many methods like `.click`, `.trigger`, `show`, `hide` etc. not working..
Some of my try..

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 function triger()
 {
  $('#trigered').trigger('click');
 }

 function trigered ()
 {
  $('#vamsi').show();
  alert('Hello. Am clicked');
 }
<script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button OnClick="triger();">Click me Button 1</button>
 <button OnClick="trigered();" id="trigered">Clicked</button>
 <div class="tab-content">
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="generalinfo">
  <h2 id="vamsi">vamsi</h2>
 </div>
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="address">
 vamsi vamsi
 </div>
 <a href="#generalinfo" aria-controls="generalinfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">General Info</a>
 <a href="#address" aria-controls="address" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="trigered" >Address</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you showed some code of your previous attempts...

Comment: This is just a sample code which i am trying to implement. My original code is very nearer to this.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I see _no code_

Comment: function triger()
 {
  $('#trigered').trigger('click');
 }

 function trigered ()
 {
  $('#vamsi').show();
  alert('Hello. Am clicked');
 }

Comment: How can i attach a image here ? so that i can show you my code

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, you could use jsfiddle and add code there. Then you could just edit your question.

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question, adding your code in text (rather than an image). That will help a lot potential answers to your question

Comment: You can use mozilla addon [`Firbug`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/). In the console part you will get the suggestions of available methods on that element. You can actually write and execute your script in the console. And also you can debug your scripts in it.

Comment: here is my fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=oclMSxNwhN

Comment: Hello @PavoDive. I had added the code to my post. please check it.

Comment: i want to show back the div who's id is "generalinfo" when a event a jquery function executes.. @PavoDive